# HTML Page to PDF Issues

Tags: coldfusion, cfdocument

The project I have is to create a Vista Print like application. I have created a very basic interface that places a resizable div in an area that can be dragged around. I am also able to place text into this div via pop-up iframe with designmode. I then write this to a database. 
I then call this data and create a pdf using Coldfusions cfdocument.

The issue is when the PDF is created the font looks slightly thicker and the word wrap is different than the html page interface which is very important. Note: The word wraps are determined by the divs height and width. It looks fine on the cfdocument process page it is just off when the pdf is created. Anyone have any ideas on this or can point me to some info that could help?

Thanks in advance.

Code Here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<cfset webRes = "96">
<cfset pxlWidth = "921">
<cfset pxlHeight = "1178">
<cfset inWidth = (pxlWidth/webres)>
<cfset inHeight = (pxlHeight/webres)>

<cfquery name="qTextData" datasource="ds">
SELECT        DocID, TextID, Width, Height, PosX, PosY, FontFamily, FontColor, FontSize, TextValue
FROM            TextEditor
WHERE        ((DocID = #session.docid#))
</cfquery>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Create PDF</title>
</head>
<cfoutput>
<cfdocument filename="mypdf.pdf" name="mypdf" fontembed="yes" format="pdf" overwrite="yes" pageheight="#inHeight#" pagewidth="#inWidth#" pagetype="custom">
    <cfdocumentsection margintop="0" marginright="0" marginbottom="0" marginleft="0">
        <body align="center" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
            <div id="pageContainer" style="background-image:url(resources/image.caspx.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; height:#pxlHeight#px; width:#pxlWidth#px;">
                <cfloop query="qTextData">
                    <div id="divTextField_#TextID#" style="position:absolute; top:#PosY#px; left:#PosX#px; width:#width#px; height:#Height#px; color:#FontColor#; font-family:#FontFamily#; font-size:#FontSize#pt; vertical-align:text-top; line-spacing:normal;">
                        #TextValue#

                    </div>                  
                </cfloop>
            </div>
        </body>
    </cfdocumentsection>
</cfdocument>
</cfoutput>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('http://linktopdf/mypdf.pdf','newWin','resizable=1');
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems a bit obvious, but just in case - you'll need to make sure the div size and the PDF box on the page are the same size. You'll also need to make sure the fonts are the same size. If you don't reproduce the web environment when converting to PDF it won't look the same.

Comment: Thanks for that but I am capturing the div size and using it to reproduce this into the pdf. I am also using the same font and pt size as well. As I stated the font looks slightly thicker on the pdf and I am wondering if the is causing the word wrap issue. But this doesn't make sense since the font and size is the same.

Comment: We can help you more if you share the relevant code.

Comment: I have add my code for the pdf creation. The query is returning these values: width:595 Height:96 posX:190 posY:606 Font: Georgia FontColor:rgb(0,0,0) FontSize:10 TextValue: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse 
mauris tortor, lacinia sed rhoncus quis, ultrices sed est. Sed tortor 
erat, auctor vel tincidunt sed, aliquam eget urna. Nunc non feugiat

Comment: You may want to consider a pdf specific CSS

Comment: retagged - removed jquery, added cfdocument

Answer (score 0):

I tried making this a comment but I started getting long winded and it was too large so it may not be the "answer" but if nothing else I'm sure it will have some helpful information in it.

What % are you viewing at and have you tried printing it out?

I've noticed that things can look lopsided or bigger than usual because they are just rendered weird in acrobat (or your PDF viewer of choice). Try adjusting the zoom and see if the display changes, also see if it prints correctly.

I have also found that like James suggested, I need special css just for the document. The CSS could be as odd as making one side of the div have a 1px larger border to make it look correct.  Also keep in mind that although you view PDFs on the screen it is still a `"print"` media. PT means 1/72 of an inch which will look bigger when you scale from your 19+ inch monitor (which is further effected by your pixel resolution) to an 8.5" x 11" piece of paper that doesn't truly know what a pixel is.  You may need to try adjusting your font size on the fly, something like: `font-size: #fontSize-2#pt;`. Change `-2` to anything that may work for your output. You could also try using a unit that scales, like `em`.

The [cfdocument docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c21.html) list all the CSS that is supported as well as identify some restrictions. It does not appear that `line-spacing:normal;` is supported. Also make sure all your CSS is included inline or in a style tag but avoid using a linked .css file.  I see you're doing that, just adding tips and pointers.

Also, according to the docs:

> ColdFusion does not return HTML and CFML outside of
>   the `<cfdocument></cfdocument>` pair.

That means ColdFusion is processing your `cfset` statements but it **does not return**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Create PDF</title>
</head>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('http://linktopdf/mypdf.pdf','newWin','resizable=1');
</script>
</html>
```

So it is possible that iText isn't rendering it as you would expect because

1. It does not have a doctype
2. It is an ill-formed HTML document

Comment: Thanks guys for your input. I will make a few adjustments and see what happens. Thanks again.